# how I can retrive the value of variable in aspx on ascx page behind

Tags: asp.net

I have `aspx code` behind

```
public partial class allahabad : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int insid = 123;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

now my code for ascx registered with above aspx page, in ascx page i have a button control on which click event I want to send the values of int insid to a targeted page , I do not want to use session . can any one help me how I can do.

**code for ascx page**

```
public partial class GFTindia_customcontrol_mycustomcontrol : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/GFTindia/targetpage.aspx?id=" + insid);
    }
}
```

Comment: You know that page class instance variables don't persist across post backs, so that anything you set in the Page_Load is set back when the click event runs, right?

Answer (score 0):

Give your User Control a public property.

```
public partial class GFTindia_customcontrol_mycustomcontrol : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public int insid { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/GFTindia/targetpage.aspx?id=" + insid, false);
    }
}
```

And you can then set or get the value from the parent page.

```
WebUserControl1.insid = insid;
```

Where `WebUserControl1` is the ID of the Control.